# How can I call add-iam-policy-binding with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I am struggling to follow the docs (https://googleapis.dev/python/iam/latest/index.html) for the GCP Python IAM Client.

How can I invoke `gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding` with this library (i.e. *without* shell'ing out)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is very useful for this type of problem because, not only does it allow you to lookup any Google service method to determine the request and response types but, it often includes sample code.

In this case `gcloud`'s `add-iam-policy-binding` maps to 2 underlying calls. `GET`'ting the policy, revising it and then `POST`'ing it back using the same eTag.

Your code should change the Policy in the response from `getIamPolicy` to create the Policy in the request for `setIamPolicy`.

The eTag is a hash of the existing policy and it's used in the `POST` to confirm to the platform, that the value you're `POST`ting is intended to replace what you received. If the value is changed before your `POST`, then the service will reject your `POST`.

Here's `setIamPolicy`:

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/setIamPolicy

And the examples (click Python):

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/setIamPolicy#examples

Another trick is to use append `--log-http` to the `gcloud` command to see what underlying REST calls are made.

Comment: This sample code ended up being the most useful for me: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iam/api-client/quickstart.py

Comment: How did you decipher that `add-iam-policy-binding` maps to 2 calls? GCP client documentation looks like an ocean of non working or missing examples to me

Comment: If you append `--log-http` to the `gcloud add-iam-policy-binding` command, you'll see that it is effected by 2 HTTP calls. The IAM service's `Policy` methods are document-oriented. You need to `GET` the current `Policy` (if any), modify it and then `POST` the updated `Policy` back to the service (with the `Policy`'s [`etag`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies#etag)) to update it.